# IOS safari css3 animations flickering

Tags: ios, css, animation, responsive

i have some problem with IOS safari browser, 
my iphone make flickering problem on some css3 animations on my site which ones have delaying etc.

I added to body

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
```

and also i tried to add this to element and parent element where is animation working. Elements displaying normal but this time my animations stop to working.

what can i do for this?

Comment: Can you add a piece of working code to your question so that the stackoverflow community can see if the behavior is recreated on their iOS devices